# get the values and pass it into the variable in to for loop on shell

Tags: shell, centos

I want to write script to get the values given lists without prefix,suffix extensions. this part was working successfully.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /aws/awstats/

for name in awstats.*.conf; do

    basename "${name#awstats.}" .conf

done
```

And then it should be passed variable in to for loop.after that that variable should run below command,

```
/usr/bin/perl -config=$variable -update
```

above command need to try repeatedly using variable.can anyone know solve to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your original loop and extending it to use your `perl` command:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cd /aws/awstats/

for name in awstats.*.conf; do
    /usr/bin/perl -config="$(basename "${name#awstats.}" .conf)" -update 
done
```

Alternatively, using a variable as you suggest,

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cd /aws/awstats/

for name in awstats.*.conf; do
    config=$(basename "${name#awstats.}" .conf)
    /usr/bin/perl -config="$config" -update 
done
```

However, the call to `perl` is a bit confusing as there seems to be an actual Perl *script* missing on the command line.  I would have assumed that the actual call would look something like

```
perl /some/path/somescript.pl -config="$config" -update
```

or just

```
/some/path/somescript.pl -config="$config" -update
```

I'm also confused as to what you mean by "concurrently". You may possibly want to run several `perl` commands at once?

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /aws/awstats/

for name in awstats.*.conf; do
    basename "${name#awstats.}" .conf
done |
xargs -I {} -P 4 /some/path/somescript.pl -config="{}" -update
```

This would keep at most four instances of the Perl script running at once.

Comment: Your first script solving my problem.Thank you very much.i will check last one also.i want to give marks but i cant give sorry for it.